# JavaScript canvas, rendering a map

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-engine

I'm trying to render my map for a game by some angle `ctx.setTransform(1, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 200);` (standard is `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`).

But then I have some lines:

[image: like a border].

Here is code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), 
 cellSize  = 50,                                 
 pic       = new Image(),                        
 map       =                                     
 [
  [{x:5,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
  [{x:4,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1}]
 ];

canvas.width  = 16 * cellSize;
canvas.height = 16 * cellSize;
ctx.setTransform(1, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 200);
pic.src = 'http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/sprite.svg';
pic.onload = function() {  
 for (var j = 0 ; j < 8; j ++)
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
    ctx.drawImage(pic, (map[i][j].x-1)*cellSize, (map[i][j].y-1)*cellSize, 50, 50, j*cellSize, i*cellSize, 50, 50);

 var pic2 = new Image(); pic2.src = 'http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/man.png';
 pic2.onload = function() {
     ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 60);
     ctx.drawImage(pic2, 150, 75);
 }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why not use phaser or something.

Comment: Don`t sure how to answer.. Just want to try it on vanilla.

Comment: Don't even bother answering the "why don't you use X" questions. Really weird issue you have there, seems like the negative skewing is "letting through" those grid lines.

Comment: Oh, it's not just the negative skewing, it's any skewing. Have you tried experimenting with that size of 50 (changing it to a power of 2)? 50 is not the ideal number for matrix operations.

Comment: "Thats a really wierd issue" is about as helpful as "why dont you use x" people are often chastised for reinventing the wheel when there are already existing solutions.

Comment: The same with 64px .

Comment: Right, I've tested it with different skewing values (you can try it here if you want to: https://jsfiddle.net/0ex7xbea/), but the seams appear as soon as it's not zero... Maybe someone like @markE could help here. The last thing that comes to my mind is to try a png instead of svg.

Comment: Quickly tried the first png I could find, and no seams: https://jsfiddle.net/0ex7xbea/2/

Comment: So it`s important to use png/jpg and not used svg?....

Comment: I can't explain it, but definitely not using an svg seems to fix it. While we're waiting for an answer, you could try saving that svg as a png and see how it behaves.

Comment: This is a common problem with the canvas :( the best thing I can suggest is simply make your grid tiles 1 pixel greater in all directions I.E. 2 extra pixels high and 2 extra pixels wide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using transforms will cause gaps between drawings that one would believe to be abutted. It is caused because drawings coordinates use floating points rather than integers and transformation math causes differences in alignment.

Probably your simplest fix is to slightly enlarge the entire scene by a very small size which will hide the alignment differences. Even +2% will usually give the desired result.

[image]

Here's your code refactored to scale to 102% of original size.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), 
 cellSize  = 50,                                 
 pic       = new Image(),                        
 map       =                                     
 [
  [{x:5,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
  [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
  [{x:4,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1}]
 ];
var scaleFix=1.02;

canvas.width  = 16 * cellSize;
canvas.height = 16 * cellSize;
ctx.setTransform(1.00, -0.5, 1.00, 0.5, 0, 200);
pic.src = 'http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/sprite.svg';
pic.onload = function() {  
 for (var j = 0 ; j < 8; j ++)
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
    ctx.drawImage(pic, (map[i][j].x-1)*cellSize, (map[i][j].y-1)*cellSize, 50, 50, j*cellSize, i*cellSize, 50*scaleFix, 50*scaleFix);

 var pic2 = new Image(); pic2.src = 'http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/man.png';
 pic2.onload = function() {
     ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 60);
     ctx.drawImage(pic2, 150*scaleFix, 75*scaleFix);
 }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Content scaled to 102% to hide transformational gaps.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ OOPS! Firefox has gone crazy with this fix. I'll be back soon with a fix for the fix :-O ]**

Ok...let's try this again. *Same Idea: increase to 102%*, but this time convert the `.svg` into a `.png` for FireFox's benefit. You can do the conversion on-the-fly by drawing the svg to a canvas and using that canvas as an image source instead of `pic` (Yes, you can `drawImage` one canvas onto another canvas). You could also do the conversion to the .svg itself and deliver a .png instead of a .svg.

Example: Converting SVG to PNG on-the-fly on the client-side:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),  
  cellSize  = 50,                                 
  pic       = new Image(),                        
  map       =                                     
  [
    [{x:5,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}], 
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
    [{x:3,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],
    [{x:4,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:1}]
  ];
var scaleFix=1.02;

canvas.width  = 16 * cellSize;
canvas.height = 16 * cellSize;
ctx.setTransform(1.00, -0.5, 1.00, 0.5, 0, 200);

var pic2=new Image();
pic2.onload=start;
pic2.src='http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/man.png';

var pic;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src='http://promodesign.kei.pl/cb/test/sprite.svg';
var imgCount=2;

function start(){
    if(--imgCount>0){return;}
    pic=document.createElement('canvas');
    pic.width=img.width;
    pic.height=img.height;
    pic.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0);
    drawScene();
    document.body.appendChild(pic);
}

function drawScene(){
    for (var j = 0 ; j < 8; j ++)
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i ++){{
        ctx.drawImage(pic, (map[i][j].x-1)*cellSize, (map[i][j].y-1)*cellSize, 50, 50, j*cellSize, i*cellSize, 50*scaleFix, 50*scaleFix);
    }}
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 60);
    ctx.drawImage(pic2, 150*scaleFix, 75*scaleFix);
}
```